# How to store and retrieve date wise data in MySQL through java?

Tags: java, mysql

I want to store and retrieve data (a single column table for each date) date wise in MySQL database through java. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/)

Answer (score 0):

Any transaction with database through java is possible using JDBC library. JDBC is a Java API that is used to connect and execute query to the database. JDBC API uses jdbc drivers to connect to the database.

Here is an overview of the basic steps involved:

1. Registering the driver class

   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
2. Creating connection

   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?" +
                                      "user=username&password=password");
3. Creating statement

   Write your MySQL query for storing or retrieving data from database date wise
4. Executing queries

   Based on the query, you may get some records returned as a result or the count of rows affected
5. Closing connection

For more details, please refer following links:

- [link1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html)
- [link2](http://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-connect-to-the-database-in-java)